# Browsing for any non-recent blog post is significantly harder with the new design

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-planned, design, blog

The new blog design looks great! But it's left behind a feature that was really useful for navigating through old content: the archive/ date-based browsing page(s).

The old blog design had date-based archive pages; e.g. https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/ *used to* lead to a nice display of all blogs posted so far in the year 2023:

[image: Screenshot of blog pre-2023 redesign, on the "yearly archives" page for the year 2023]

There were even [monthly](https://web.archive.org/web/20230507233158/https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/02/) and [daily](https://web.archive.org/web/20230507233137/https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/02/03/) versions!

But now, links to the archive pages lead to a 404, and there doesn't appear to be any way to browse in any date-conscious means *at all*. Only the newest posts under a given tag are visible, and no sort options are available.

Has the feature been relocated somewhere that I've missed? If not, can we have it back please? It was especially useful for tracking down old posts where I know the time frame but not other details.

---

<del>The "Show more" button at the bottom of those tag pages ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.blog/podcast/)) also appears to be broken; clicking it generates [a console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ru39W.png) and shows a spinner that spins forever.</del> ([Since fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1313225))

Comment: "Show more" should be working now!

Comment: Yes, it [broke a lot of links](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2019/12/31/the-secret-index-of-all-stack-overflow-blog-posts#TheList).